# Mobile landing page brand and logo position

Tags: html, css

I need help fixing my sites brand and logo on mobile [transition center online](http://wwrfresource.com) it displays ok on desktop but not centered on mobile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at your website. It appears that you are manually centering your logo using CSS such as `margin` and `padding`. Instead of doing this, try instead using centering commands. [This guide](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_align.asp) gives some tips on how to properly center objects. You could also use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to have a different manual centering when using mobile.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove these 2 commands on mobile then it will be centered:

```
section#brand {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```